# How to return generic type as an exact type based on the type of T in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, types

I have some trouble with my homework C# code.

The question: I made a generic method with a return type of T and an integer parameter. What does the method do is the following: 
- check the type of T.
-if the type is ClassA then it should return ClassA type.
-if the type is ClassB then it should return ClassB type.
-if the type is ClassC then it should return ClassC type.

I can check the type of T with the code of:

```
Type theType = typeof(T);
```

Then i check:

```
if(theType.Equals(typeof(ClassA))
{
Return ClassA.FindByID(the given parameter);
}
```

However, the visual studio tells me that “Cannot inplicitly convert type ‘ClassA’ to ‘T’. I tried cast is like 
`return (ClassA)blah blah blah;`
but the visual studio keeps telling me this error.

I'm afraid I do this whole thing the other way around and I think this could have been done much simpler. So, how could I return the needed type?

Thanks for your help.

PS.: sorry for any mistakes. I'm not a native English speaker, and this is my first time using StackOverflow :)

I've tried to cast it explicitly like:

```
return (ClassA) ClassA.FindById(Id);
```

But I got the same error message mentioned above.

Here is my full method.

```
public T GetById<T>(int Id)
{
   Type elementType = typeof(T);

   if(elementType.Equals(typeof(ClassA))
   {
      return ClassA.FindById(Id);
   }

   if(elementType.Equals(typeof(ClassB))
   {
      return ClassB.FindById(Id);
   }

   if(elementType.Equals(typeof(ClassC))
   {
      return ClassC.FindById(Id);
   }
}
```

Comment: The compiler is correct. You haven't provided any type constraints so it can't know whether `T` and `ClassA` etc can be cast to each other. Why are you using such code though? What are you trying to do? There's no benefit to this code over calling the `Find` methods directly.

Comment: Another problem here is the use of static methods. If you *didn't* use a static method, you wouldn't need to check the type at all. You could implement eg an `IFinder` interface in each class and call its `FindById` method directly.

Comment: @ilkerkaran there's no object instance here. The OP is trying to call a static method based on a type.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are both right about the composition and my previous comment.

Comment: Let me explain my problem in more details as why am I trying to do this in the first place: There is a localDB in the Data layer with EntityFramework on it. I made a Repository class in the Repo layer for all the Entities, containing the CRUD methods. I also made a Repository class for the DBModel. I intended to use this DBModelRepo as a 'leader' class for all the EntityRepos. Therefore in the BusinessLogic layer, all I need to do is call the ModelRepo's GetById method (the method in the question) with the right Entity type and this method should give me the Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an Interface implementation issue more than a generic type issue. Consider, if you have an interface IEntity, you would specify that it has to have a function "IEntity FindById(int Id)". You'd then implement that function in ClassA, ClassB and ClassC (which it kind of looks like you already have).

I have no idea where you implemented your FindById<T>(int id) but it seems to me that all you need to do is include the method in your interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    IEntity FindById(int Id);
}

public class ClassA : IEntity
{
    IEntity IEntity.FindById(int Id)
    {
        IEntity returnvalue = null;

        //do some specific stuff to get the entity
        return returnvalue;
    }
}

public class ClassB : IEntity
{
    IEntity IEntity.FindById(int Id)
    {
        IEntity returnvalue = null;

        //do some specific stuff to get the entity
        return returnvalue;
    }
}

public class ClassC : IEntity
{
    IEntity IEntity.FindById(int Id)
    {
        IEntity returnvalue = null;

        //do some specific stuff to get the entity
        return returnvalue;
    }
}

public static class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        IEntity EA = new ClassA();
        IEntity EB = new ClassB();
        IEntity EC = new ClassC();

        EA.FindById(1);
        EB.FindById(2);
        EB.FindById(3);
    }
}
```

In this manner, you don't really type check anything.

Answer (score 0):

All right. So I figured it out that I need to create an inteface and then implement it in ClassA and ClassB. So that way I removed the errors mentioned in the question.
My code looks like this now:

```
public ClassA : IEntity

public ClassB: IEntity

public ClassC: IEntity
```

```
public IEntity FindById<T>(int ID)
{
   Type elementType = typeof(T);

   if(elementType.Equals(typeof(ClassA))
   {
      return ClassA.FindById(ID);
   }

   if(elementType.Equals(typeof(ClassB))
   {
      return ClassB.FindById(ID);
   }

   if(elementType.Equals(typeof(ClassC))
   {
      return ClassC.FindById(ID);
   }
}
```